# How to measure word similarity using wordnet for the information theoretic definition as detailed in Resnik 1995?

Tags: nlp, information-theory

[Resnik 1995](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cmp-lg/9511007.pdf) equation 3 uses count(n) to define P(c). What is count(n)?

Any solved example would be appreciated.